# PHP: How do I access a local varibale of a function in class from another function

Tags: php, function, variables, scope

So i have a php class and i'm having a small snarl up. imagine a class as one shown below

```
<?php
class Foo
{
   public function __construct()
  {
     $this->bar1();
  }
  public function bar1()
  {
    $myvar = 'Booya!';

   return 'Something different';
  }
  public function bar2()
  {
    //get value of $myvar from bar1()
  }
}
$new_foo = new Foo();
$new_foo->bar2();
?>
```

Question is, 
how do I access the variable `$myvar` from `bar1()` keeping in mind that `bar1()` returns something different.

Comment: Save it as a class property, eg `$this->myvar`?

Answer (score 2):

You would do something like this... Everything has been explained through comments next to the code.

```
<?php
class Foo
{
    private $myvar; //<---- Declare the variable !
    public function __construct()
    {
        $this->bar1();
    }
    public function bar1()
    {
        $this->myvar = 'Booya!'; //<---- Use this $this keyword

        //return 'Something different';//<--- Comment it.. Its not required !
    }
    public function bar2()
    {
        return $this->myvar; //<----- You need to add the return keyword
    }
}
$new_foo = new Foo();
echo $new_foo->bar2(); //"prints" Booya!
```

Answer (score 2):

```
<?php
class Foo
{
  var $myvar;
  public function __construct()
  {
     $this->bar1();
  }
  public function bar1()
  {
    $this->myvar = 'Booya!';

   return 'Something different';
  }
  public function bar2()
  {
    //get value of $myvar from bar1()
    echo $this->myvar;
  }
}
$new_foo = new Foo();
$new_foo->bar2();
?>
```

You should set it as a class variable first, then access it using `$this`

Answer (score 2):

You cannot do that directly, only you can do without altering bar1() return value is create a 
class variable for saving the value of this data
In class definition add

```
private $saved_data;
```

In bar1():

```
$myvar = 'Booya!';
$this->saved_data = $myvar;
```

And in bar2()

```
$myvar_from_bar1 = $this->saved_data
```

Answer (score 0):

Use class variables like:

```
$this->myvar = 'Booya!';
```

Now the variable myvar will be store in the class and can be requested or altered in other methods.